# Security Exception When i am trying to run working asp code on one system from another system

Tags: asp.net, security, webmatrix

I have one asp code which is working perfectly on one system. I am using Microsoft web matrix to run it. But when I am trying to run it in another system, I am getting some errors:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Security Exception
>
> Description: The application attempted to perform an operation not
>   allowed by the security policy.  To grant this application the
>   required permission please contact your system administrator or change
>   the application's trust level in the configuration file.
>
> Exception Details: System.Security.SecurityException: The source was
>   not found, but some or all event logs could not be searched. 
>   Inaccessible logs: Security.
>
> Source Error:

```
Line 136:        catch (Exception ex1)
Line 137:        {
Line 138:            EventLog.WriteEntry("GLOBAL_ASAX.Session_Start", ex1.Message + ": " + ex1.StackTrace, EventLogEntryType.Error);         
Line 139:        }
Line 140:    }
```

> Source File: c:\Users\sysadmin\Documents\NET2_VXLICENSING_Web\Global.asax    Line: 138
>
> Stack Trace:

```
[SecurityException: The source was not found, but some or all event logs could not be searched.  Inaccessible logs: Security.]
   System.Diagnostics.EventLog.FindSourceRegistration(String source, String machineName, Boolean readOnly) +665
   System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists(String source, String machineName) +104
   System.Diagnostics.EventLog.VerifyAndCreateSource(String sourceName, String currentMachineName) +75
   System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry(String message, EventLogEntryType type, Int32 eventID, Int16 category, Byte[] rawData) +205
   System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry(String source, String message, EventLogEntryType type, Int32 eventID, Int16 category, Byte[] rawData) +87
   System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry(String source, String message, EventLogEntryType type) +14
   ASP.global_asax.Session_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\sysadmin\Documents\NET2_VXLICENSING_Web\Global.asax:138
   System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.RaiseOnStart(EventArgs e) +8879616
   System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.CompleteAcquireState() +237
   System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.BeginAcquireState(Object source, EventArgs e, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +504
   System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +66
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.5485; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.5491

I searched a lot on the internet about it but nothing is working. I also updated registry keys.

Comment: What was the original, and what was the final operating systems?